# check in SQLite db item does not exist

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I've got a little 5 image display thing with a button to see the next 5.

if say someone hits the next button and there are only 2 more images to show, the next two are shown but after that the JavaScript crashes

Is there a way I can check to see if the next item I'm trying to get exists or not

here is what I'm using to get the item from the DB and "genre_count" is my image counter 
for displaying image 1,2,3...

```
......
film_list = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE genre = "Drama"');
.....
...
film_item = film_list.rows.item(genre_count).image   

return film_item
```

Can I do something like this pseudo code

```
if (film_list.rows.item(genre_count).image === empty)
      film_item=""
  else   
    film_item = film_list.rows.item(genre_count).image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a variable film_list.rows.length that tells you the number of rows that were returned.

Just compare against that to know when to stop returning new items.